# Clear previous tests in RSpec while running new tests using Guard

Tags: rspec, tdd, guard

Looking for a way to clear the terminal when a new test result appears. I now feel cluttered in having the new test results appended before clearing the old tests. Any way to have it done?

My guard file:

```
guard :rspec do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://github.com/guard/guard#-c--clear-option):

`bundle exec guard --clear`

Comment: can we add this line to our `Guardfile` or `.rspec`? I'm not sure which one

Comment: @mbigras you can add a line with just `clearing: on` in your `Guardfile` outside of the `guard do` block to achieve the same effect.

Comment: small correction – add `clearing :on` to your `Guardfile`, not `clearing: on` https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Guardfile-DSL---Configuring-Guard#clearing